# How to access vector<Vec4i> values

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I want to get vector points for example:

```
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
```

`hierarchy[0]=[23,34,45,56];
hierarchy[1]=[45,12,0,99];`

```
hierarchy[0].point[0]=23;
hierarchy[0].point[3]=56;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `.point` method on the `vec4i` object, you may simply access the values as you access a 2D array.

```
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

hierarchy[0]=[23,34,45,56];
hierarchy[1]=[45,12,0,99];

hierarchy[0][0]=23;
hierarchy[0][3]=56;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Watched this question after 3.5 years. What a fool I was that time.